# Does "Enchanted" by Elizabeth Lowell have a Lie Detector Witch?

Tags: medieval-series, elizabeth-lowell

[TVTropes - Lie Detector](https://tvtropes.org/Main/LieDetector):

> In the medieval Romance Novel *Enchanted*, the heroine has a friend of hers, a witch with this power, hold the hand of the knight who raped her so that she can interrogate him in front of her doubting husband. Once she's vindicated, her husband himself uses the woman's power to assure her that he believes her and is remorseful about not having done so before.

The editor's edit history over multiple years pretty clearly [implies](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/article_history.php?article=Main.BlondeBrunetteRedhead&more=t#edit4056701) that [*Medieval Series #3: Enchanted* by Elizabeth Lowell](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/768321.Enchanted) is the book under discussion.

And [apparently](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/177983854), witches *do* exist in the story, but does the *lie-detecting* witch exist?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, the lie detecting witch is Lady Amber of Stone Ring Keep. She is described as:

> Ariane’s breath caught. Warily she eyed the Learned lady of Stone Ring Keep, who could discern truth simply by touching someone.

In chapter 28 Ariane confronts the knight *Geoffrey* who raped her. Geoffrey has been trying to provoke her husband into a duel, but this threatens an uneasy peace. Ariane requests Geoffrey be questioned "in the Learned manner":

> Sir Geoffrey has insulted the honor of Lady Ariane. The lady has most forcefully requested that the issue not be solved by test of arms, for such would only jeopardize the peace that the Glendruid Wolf has worked so tirelessly to
> maintain.”
>
> A murmuring went through the assembled knights. Each knew what was at issue. Each had wondered why Simon had not challenged Geoffrey ten days ago, nor any day since.
>
> Now they knew.
>
> “Instead,” Meg continued, “Ariane requested that Sir Geoffrey be put to the question in the Learned manner. Lady Amber has agreed.”

However Lady Amber does not hold Geoffrey's hand but instead touches his cheek:

> Amber took a breath and let it out slowly, composing herself. Then she rested one fingertip on Geoffrey’s cheek just above the place where blood had been drawn by Erik’s knife.
>
> As soon as Amber touched Geoffrey, she went pale. Sweat stood clearly on her skin. Her eyes were so dilated they were almost black. Only her clenched jaw kept her from crying out. Whatever Amber sensed of Geoffrey when she touched him was intensely painful to her. Yet touching Geoffrey was the only way Amber could learn his truth.

I'm not sure I'd call Lady Amber a *witch* though. She is a *Learned* and while gifted they are not really witches. When Geoffrey insults her by calling her a witch she responds:

> Without a word Amber reached inside her tunic with her free hand and drew out a silver cross. Bloodred amber gleamed at five points of the cross that lay nestled in her cool hand. Her fingers closed around the cross for the space of four slow breaths, then opened again. There was no mark anywhere on Amber’s hand, no sign that the cross burned in protest at being held against her skin.
>
> Geoffrey looked to the lord’s table, where Blackthorne’s chaplain sat.
>
> “What say you, chaplain?” Geoffrey shouted.
>
> “Have no fear of Satan within this keep,” the chaplain said in a voice that carried easily the length of the great hall. “Lady Amber is like Lady Margaret, strangely blessed by God.”

Comment: Thanks! Wow, much quote!

Comment: @Malady If you're happy with the answer please will you click the tick symbol to the left of my answer to mark it as accepted. Thanks :-)

Comment: It *is* a pretty good answer. IIRC even though, I should wait before checking it off, in hopes that an even better answer arrives?
...
Hmm, is Amber a friend of Ariane? Or just *someone she knows*?

Comment: @Malady In general, if an answer directly and succinctly answers everything you asked, there is no harm in marking it as correct.  *IF* someone comes along and somehow provides a better answer, you can always unmark the original answer and change to the new one.  But I'd argue that it is better to mark an answer as correct (when it is indeed correct) early than to wait, and inevitably forget; leaving the question as "unanswered" when a correct answer has been provided.

Comment: @Malady Amber is more of an elder sister figure than a bosom buddy to Ariane. In book 2 Ariane comes to Stone Ring Keep because she is betrothed to the keep's Lord Duncan. However neither want the match - it's a purely political manoeuvre - and to the relief of all parties Duncan marries Amber instead. Ariane meets Amber at Stone Ring Keep and is on good terms with her despite the matrimonial manoeuvrings.